# Can someone explain Technicolor?

Tags: particle-physics, higgs, beyond-the-standard-model

I read [Wikipedia on Technicolor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technicolor_(physics)) (and understood some of it - I am not a scientist)

Can someone give me a layman's definition?

Is the technicolor theory dead now that the Higgs has been found?  Can Technicolor exist along side the Higgs or is it an either-or thing?

Comment: As the Wikipedia article explains, “a Higgs-like boson with mass approximately $125\,\text{GeV/c}^2$ ... is not generically predicted by technicolor models, but can be accommodated by them.”

Comment: The vanilla version of Technicolor is dead as doornail, given the insurmountable obstacles like FCNC. That being said, some ad hoc variants of Technicolor are still hanging in there.